# Multiple users assigned to the same session ID (express-session)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, express-session

I am using `express session` and `MongoStore` for storing session ID

Here is my app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

var user = require('./models/userModel');

//------Connect to database
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/porto', { useMongoClient: true });

//------Config Passport
require('./config/passport.js')(passport);

//------Adding middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret : 'secret',
  saveUninitialized : true,
  resave : true,
  store  : new MongoStore({mongooseConnection : mongoose.connection})
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
```

My route handler for posting a ToDo

```js
app.post('/addTodo',function(req,res){

  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.user._id);  // Here the user id is changed
  console.log(req.sessionID); // Here the sessionID never changed, but assigned to the newly logged in user

  var todo = req.body.todo;

  userModel.update(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    { $push: { todos: todo } },
    function(err,done){
      if (err)
      return err;
    return done;
    }
  );
  res.redirect('/profile');
});
```

Comment: And, what exactly is the question?  And, what exactly are the steps to reproduce it?

Comment: The questions is , same session id should not be assigned to different users how to solve that?

Comment: Please describe what are the exact steps to reproduce seeing the exact same session ID assigned to completely different users and which exact value are you seeing the same?

Comment: Since i am using 'app.use(session);' when i visit the website the middleware always assign me the same sessionID everytime, if i logged in with account 'A' and check the database using robomongo i see that this sessionID is pointing to the latest user that is logged in, i don't know why is that happening

Comment: Why are you using both `connect-mongo` and `passport`?  Aren't they conflicting?  Shouldn't you pick one or the other, but not both?

Comment: No they are not conflicting, passport for authenticating users(serialize/deserialize) and connect-mongo for only handling session

Comment: Well, you're also using passport and Mongo for session handling.

Comment: Should i remove app.use(passport.session()); then? or what should i do,
Actually if i removed connect-mongo there will be no sessions stored in the database therefore when the server restart current logged in users will be logged off, and also i read before that passport needs session by default to work, am i wrong?

Comment: Well, the whole point of `new MongoStore({mongooseConnection : mongoose.connection})` in your `app.use(session(...))` is to tell express-session to use your mongo db to store sessions.  If you do that correctly, then express-session will put the sessions in your DB with just that single part of the code.  You don't need something else to cause the sessions to go in your DB.

Comment: Update: i removed app.use(passport.session()); and whole passport authentication did not work